# Matlab Deciding Output based on matrix condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

So I have this matrix

```
A=
7

B=
0.34   0.34   0.34
0.50   0.25   0.25
```

and this matrix

```
C=
1
1
4
2
3
6
3
```

with this rule:

- if C=1 then the output = sum(A*(B first row) )
- if C=2 then the output = sum(A*(B 2nd row) )
- if C is not 1 or 2 then output = C value

or in general:

- if the C-th row exist in B then the output = sum(A*(C-th row of B) )
- otherwise output = C value

So the output should be like this:

```
output=
7.14
7.14
4
7
3
6
3
```

I'm trying using this code but its doesn't work

```
sizeA=size(A,1)
sizeB=size(B,1)
for i=1:sizeB
    if (B(i)<=sizeA)
        Output=sum(repmat(A,1,length(C))'.*B(C,:),2)
    else 
        Output=C(i)
    end
end
```

Comment: Is your condition dependent on the number of rows in `B`? If a third row exists, should one use it or not? Please mention it in your question if this is the case. Formulating your question well is often a large step in finding the solution.

Comment: yeps its depends on rows in B, so if there is 3rd row on B, it should be count too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
sizeA=size(A,1);
sizeB=size(B,1);
sizeC=size(C,1);
Output = zeros(size(C)); % preallocate memory for efficiency
for i=1:sizeC
    if C(i)<=sizeB
        Output(i)=sum(A * B(C(i), :));
    else 
        Output(i)=C(i);
    end
end
```

You can also avoid a for loop in the following way:

```
% make B of the same size as C
B_ = zeros(size(C)); 
B_(1:size(B, 1)) = sum(B, 2);
% calculate the output
output = C .* (C > size(B, 1)) + A .* B_(C)
```

*Please try to understand the code and not to just use it.*

Answer (score 0):

I simplified a little bit. It works.

```
for i=1:length(C)
num=C(i);
switch num
case 1
output(i)=sum(A*B(1,:))
case 2
output(i)=sum(A*B(2,:))
otherwise
output(i)=C(i);
end
end

output =

  Columns 1 through 5

    7.1400    7.1400    4.0000    7.0000    3.0000

  Columns 6 through 7

    6.0000    3.0000
```

Comment: Although it is not explicitly requested, this does not work for general `B` matrices with a different number of rows.

Comment: No, because you will not use the extra rows or access unexisting ones. Based on the code he provided, I think he wants to use the row if `B` if it exists.

Comment: Actually it depends on rows in B